# Как добавить динамическое MenuStrip в Windows Forms, которое лежит в SQlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Добрый день. Я создаю приложение на C# и использую SQlite. Хочу строковое меню вывести из базы `database.db` таблицы `MenuBar`. Мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Finisar.SQLite;

namespace ПАК
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
            SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
            SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

            sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

            sqlite_conn.Open();

            sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

            sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string text = sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT text FROM MenuBar";

            string count  = sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MenuBar";

            int numVal = Int32.Parse(count);

            if (sqlite_datareader.Read()==true)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numVal; i++)
                {
                    this.menuStrip1.Text = "text";
                }
                //System.Console.WriteLine(sqlite_datareader["text"]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

База :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Несколько коментариев.

Вы сначала вызываете `ExecuteReader`, а только потом формируете текст команды:

```
sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
string text = sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT text FROM MenuBar";
```

Естественно, из БД ничего не вернется. Дальше Вы зачем-то переопределяете текст команды:

```
string text = sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT text FROM MenuBar";
string count  = sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MenuBar";
```

В этом случае команда будет получать только количество. Если нужно выполнить еще один запрос - создавайте новую команду.

Здесь Вы просто в цикле присваиваете `"text"` свойству `menuStrip1.Text`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numVal; i++)
{
    this.menuStrip1.Text = "text";
}
```

**Ответ:**

```
private void menuStrip1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;"))
    {
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT text FROM MenuBar", sqlite_conn))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {                    
                    string text = reader["text"].ToString();
                    ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem(text);
                    menuStrip1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если нужно удалить элементы меню, то:

```
foreach(ToolStripMenuItem it in menuStrip1.Items)
{
    menuStrip1.Items.Remove(it);
}
```

Comment: Только заметил ответ. Спасибо! Сейчас буду пробовать. У меня ещё возник вопрос, из-за того что событие menuStrip1_Load, не происходит, когда форма запускается. На какое его можно заменить или лучше в Form1.Designer.cs убрать код?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, чтобы происходило при запуске формы, добавьте тогда в событие `Form_Load`

Answer (score -1):

На msdn есть [примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip(v=vs.110).aspx) смотрите после описания файла.

Это из того примера:

```
// Create a MenuStrip control with a new window.
MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
ToolStripMenuItem windowMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem("Window");
ToolStripMenuItem windowNewMenu = 
    new ToolStripMenuItem("New", null, new EventHandler(windowNewMenu_Click));
windowMenu.DropDownItems.Add(windowNewMenu);
((ToolStripDropDownMenu)(windowMenu.DropDown)).ShowImageMargin = false;
((ToolStripDropDownMenu)(windowMenu.DropDown)).ShowCheckMargin = true;

// Assign the ToolStripMenuItem that displays 
// the list of child forms.
ms.MdiWindowListItem = windowMenu;

// Add the window ToolStripMenuItem to the MenuStrip.
ms.Items.Add(windowMenu);

// Dock the MenuStrip to the top of the form.
ms.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

// The Form.MainMenuStrip property determines the merge target.
this.MainMenuStrip = ms;

// Add the MenuStrip last.
// This is important for correct placement in the z-order.
this.Controls.Add(ms);
```

По идее вам надо в цикле повторить строчку:

```
ms.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("New");
```